# MacOS Ventura : double-clicking on a file to open it with currently active version of software

Tags: macos, ventura

I have multiple versions of InDesign on my computer. Before using Ventura when I double-clicked on a file, it opened with the Indesign version that was running and not the default version of the program. Is there a way to set this parameter in Ventura?

I have done some research but haven't found anything on this subject. I do know I could right-click on the file and select the right version or open the file from the Indesign interface and that is what I currently do, but double-clicking is just way more intuitive. Thank you!

Comment: I’ve had multiple versions of Photoshop installed at one time and do not recall this behavior. It always opened the latest version.

Comment: @Allan I just tried with two different versions of Pages (7.1 and 12.1 on two different volumes) in Big Sur and it did behave as Maria described it, i.e. the pages document opened in the one that was running at the time.

Comment: If you have both versions in your Dock you could drag the file to whichever version you want to open it in.